# pssh error while connecting solaris servers

Tags: bash, ssh, solaris

I am using pssh to run a script on remote server. For linux I am not getting issue but for solaris I am having the issue while running the script.

I am using shebang to use bash shell and it is using sh shell which is causing the issue.

```
# cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

UNAME=$(uname)
if [ $UNAME = SunOS ]; then 
    echo SunOS
fi


# ssh host1 'bash -s' <test.sh 
SunOS

# pssh -H host1 -i -I <test.sh 
[1] 04:15:47 [FAILURE] host1 Exited with error code 2
Stderr: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
-sh: syntax error: `UNAME=$' unexpected
#
```

Comment: Does the Solaris box have `bash` installed?

Comment: Yes, it has . Working fine with `ssh` command with out any issues. But only problem with `pssh` command

Answer (score 2):

The shebang being only processed when an executable is run, not when reading stdin, is ignored by both Linux and Solaris. It happens that Linux `sh` is actually `bash` so supports the syntax you use.

The simpler workaround would be to fix the script to make it portable to any shell:

```
UNAME=`uname`
if [ "$UNAME" = SunOS ]; then 
    echo SunOS
fi
```

Alternatively, you might change the default shell of the remote user to something more standard, like `ksh` or `bash`.